# Tooltip not working with Ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tooltip

I would like to use the tooltip function from jQuery UI. When I use

```
$('.notice').tooltip();
```

it is not working and nothing happens.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<i title="hello world" id="1" class="fa fa-comment-o notice comment_form"></i>
```

It is weird because it works when I use

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

My HTML code is coming from a dynamic Ajax request. Could that be the problem? If so, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you wrap it in a document.ready? e.g.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.notice').tooltip();
        });
```

I suspect its more about your jquery/dom not being loaded on time? Do you see any errors in the console when you use your first code?

```
$('.notice').tooltip();
```

Comment: I am already using `$(document).ready(function(){` and no, I am not getting any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this...

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: ".notice",
    content: function () {
        return $(this).attr("title");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to test it but I don't have the code anymore, since the question is over 4 years old ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. I forget to look at the dates. ;)